# Borders won't round with border-radius

Tags: html, css, html-table

So I'm coding a webpage, and I was coding some CSS attributes into a table, but the border didn't round with the background when I used the border-radius attribute. It just stays at a corner. Here's my code, thanks in advance!

PS: My browser is chrome, My text editor is brackets and my pc is a windows 10.

```html
<table style= "background-color: orange; font-family:monospace, sans-serif; border-width: thick; border-style: double; border-radius: 40px;"> <tr> <td> filler</td> <td> filler</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Not really sure what's not working, run the code snippet in your question. - I'm using Chrome on Windows 10

Comment: Maybe it's the text editor acting up?..

Comment: Your code is working as expected, what are you trying to do? what is the expected output?

Comment: It's not working in my text editor...

Comment: if you can link to a sandbox displaying the issue it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to include the border-radius attribute in the cell. It worked as I wanted it to, what I was seeing was the border of the cell.